# PHP SOAP-Client multiple elements

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I want to make a request like that, where it is optional to give any number of "SomeNumber" as input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope><SOAP-ENV:Body></
 <ns1:Request>
  <ns1:SomeNumber>42</ns1:SomeNumber>
  <ns1:SomeNumber>1</ns1:SomeNumber>
  <ns1:SomeNumber>4</ns1:SomeNumber>
  <ns1:SomeCode>12</ns1:SomeCode>
 </ns1:Request>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In those cases, where I only have 1 SomeNumber it works fine, but when I want to request for more than one result, I only get 1 result. (Which is normal, because the value of SomeNumber only changes for every value in $arrChr).

```
$objClient = new SOAPClient("wsdl", array("trace" => 1));
$arrRequest = array('Request' => array('SomeNumber' => $arrChr[0],
                           'SomeNumber' => $arrChr[1], 
                           'SomeCode' => $intSpeciescode));     
$objResult = $objClient->something($arrRequest);
```

But is there a way to handle multiple SomeNumber, like in the request above?

I hope someone can help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. The only way to do it, is to pass in an indexed array. The SOAP server should handle this without any issue (at least, it did for me). If I got it right, `$arrChr` is already an indexed array, so you could use something like this:

```
$objClient = new SOAPClient("wsdl", array("trace" => 1));
$arrRequest = array(
  'Request' => array(
    'SomeNumber' => $arrChr, 
    'SomeCode' => $intSpeciescode
  )
);
$objResult = $objClient->something($arrRequest);
```

When you are handling the result, and the result has a field, which repeats as well, then PHP's SOAPClient would collapse it to an indexed array as well. The way I process them is usually using `is_array()`:

```
if (is_array($objResult->SomeNumber)) {
  foreach ($objResult as $result) {
    // do stuff on $result
  }
} else {
  // do stuff on $objResult->SomeNumber
}
```